# Assigning a reactive form control in Angular 4 to disabled, not sure how or if to use patchValue

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a user form in my app. I create the form in my component in a  Reactive Forms way. In some scenarios I want to set the form controls so they are disabled and the user cannot interact with them. My (reduced) code looks like so...

```
constructor(private usersService: UsersService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
// I create the readonly boolean

public isReadOnly: boolean = false;
private buildMyForm(): void {
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      StatusID: [{value: '', disabled: this.isReadOnly}, Validators.required],
      AddressID: [{value: '', disabled: this.isReadOnly}, Validators.required],
      Comments: [{value: '', disabled: this.isReadOnly}, Validators.maxLength(250)],
      Description: [{value: '', disabled: this.isReadOnly}, Validators.maxLength(250)],
    });
  }


public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.buildForm(); // create the form
  this.usersService.loadUser().subscribe((response:UserData) => {
    // lots of info but we are interested in response.readonly which is a boolean
    if(response.readonly) {
       this.isReadOnly = response.readonly;
    }
  });
}
```

As you can see I determine if the form should be read only once the `usersService.loadUser()` has returned a value, now by this time my formBuilder has already constructed the form and the `disabled` status will not be affected if the `response.readonly` is true. Should I move the `this.buildForm();` into the subscription the app errors as the HTML wants the formBuilder `[formGroup]="userForm"`. I've been reading on how I could update the form controls but nothing so far has worked, I thought I could use `.patchValue` like so

```
if(response.readonly) {
this.isReadOnly = response.readonly;
  this.userForm.patchValue({
    // set the disabled status for StatusID, AddressID:, Comments:, Description
  });
}
```

However I am unsure if this is the correct way to go about this... I am not wanting to update the value? I'm currently reading the docs but usually people here are much quicker than me so if anyone can help please point me in the right direction.

**Before I forget** - I know I can add a condition to my HTML template using `[disabled]="isReadOnly"` or `[readonly]="isReadOnly"`, I just thought it would be a better approach to have the logic in the component, not the template...

Comment: Hi there is a `disable()` method on the `formControl`that might do what you want: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

Comment: Take a look at this thread too: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11271#issuecomment-289806196
Perhaps you can bind your isReadOnly property in your view with `[attr.disabled]`

Answer (score 1):

you can `enable()` to enable the disabled field

to enable field by control

```
this.userForm.controls.StatusID.enable();
```

or simply

```
this.userForm.enable();
```

will enable all the disabled fields

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer, it was to set the items to disabled like so:

```
if(response.readonly) {
    this.userForm.get('StatusID').disable();
    this.userForm.get('AddressID').disable();
    this.userForm.get('Comments').disable();
   this.userForm.get('Description').disable();
}
```